# Displaying formatted table

Tags: perl

I'm trying to display output in table format but having some trouble.

I have a few variables that contain strings separated by spaces for example:

```
$var1 = "1 1003 33 40 9948";
$var2 = "2";
```

I want the table to look like this:

I want to display the table such that it looks like this:

```
Column1 Column2
======= =======
   1       2
 1003      
  33
  40
 9948
```

I want the contents of var1 to wrap down for each value.

I'm able to display the header no problem. I've been trying to use perl's format:

```
^|||||~~^|||||~~^|||||~~^|||||~~^|||||~~

$var1    $var2   $var3   $var4  $var4  
.
```

...but it's not working well.

The number's don't line up correct and I've tried to padding so that I force them to wrap but they line up unevenly. The contents of the table are being displayed through a foreach loop:

```
Column1 Column2
======= =======
 1          2
1003
  33
40
9948
```

I hope I'm clear on what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

In general, I haven't found Perl’s patterns to be terribly reliable. They’re really useful for a few things, but generally require more work than it seems like they should.

The previous answer shows a more standard right-justification (which makes sense for numbers), but you seem to want a centered justification. What I don't understand, however, is why you’re using `^|||||` instead of `@|||||`. The former will attempt to wrap text on multiple lines if necessary; that’s not really what you want here. You should probably be using `@|||||` instead.

Furthermore, there’s no need to use

```
^|||||~~^|||||~~^|||||~~^|||||~~^|||||~~
```

because the first `~~` will allow the pattern to be repeated indefinitely.

That said, I think you would get a lot more control over the process by generating the text yourself rather than relying on Perl’s formats.

```
sub centerText {
    my ($text, $width) = @_;
    my $pad = ( length($text) < $width )
        ? ' ' x int(($width - length($text)) / 2)
        : '';
    return "$pad$text";
}
```

Then you’d just use:

```
printf "%-7s %-7s\n", 'Column1', 'Column2';
printf "%-7s %-7s\n", '=======', '=======';
printf "%-7s %-7s\n", centerText($val1[1], 7), centerText($val2[1], 7);
```

or somesuch.

That make any sense?